# Android Cannot Detect Bluetooth Device

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-bluetooth

I am having a problem with my broadcast receiver and finding a particular device. Earlier in my program, I look for the current devices and allow the user to pick on. That name and address is saved off. When the application processes its "onResume", I create a broadcast receiver.

All I am attempting to do is see if the previously saved device is in the area. It doesn't *have* to be paired, but must at least be seen. I don't see any of these toast messages. I have even attempted to put the device into discover-able mode prior to this.

Here is my broadcast receiver.

```
mBluetoothReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceAddress = device.getAddress();

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BT Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

                if (deviceAddress.equals(mDeviceAddress)) {
                    Toast toasty = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct BT Device Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toasty.show();
                }
            }
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceAddress = device.getAddress();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BT Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

                if (deviceAddress.equals(mDeviceAddress)) {
                    Toast toasty = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct BT Device Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toasty.show();
                }
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Broadcast Error : " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    this.registerReceiver(mBluetoothReceiver, filter);

    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    this.registerReceiver(mBluetoothReceiver, filter);

    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    this.registerReceiver(mBluetoothReceiver, filter);

    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    this.registerReceiver(mBluetoothReceiver, filter);

    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
    this.registerReceiver(mBluetoothReceiver, filter);

    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    this.registerReceiver(mBluetoothReceiver, filter);
```

**Edit**

It seems that the connected and disconnection events are being detected properly. They are only detected on change. However, the ACTION_FOUND is not. I cannot simply be in the area of the device.

Comment: did u set permissions?
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

Comment: Yes, the permissions are set.

Comment: So it appears to somewhat work. I have to actually go to another activity then return to this activity. This register is in the onResume code. Any reason why it wouldn't work the first time, but all the others it would?